# Stored procedure returns "Timeout expired"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In my Windows application, I use SQL Server 2008. My database size is 5086080 KB. Now I get the error as timeout expired when saving a transaction by using a stored procedure. So I set command timeout to 1200. It works fine. But I think it shouldn't because insert data have 2 or 3 lines. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

This is detail error message:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding .

Answer (score 1):

Timeout is entirely on how long the actual SQL command is likely to take.

For example example, most of our commands run sproc's that should take no longer than 30 seconds to complete, however there are a couple that run for much longer, which means they have their own high valued timeouts.

You'll need to profile how long on average your routine takes then adjust the timeout accordingly, and remember to leave room for variables like latency etc

Answer (score 0):

you need to profile your sql query and your code at every step. only then will you be able to know the exact bottleneck in your program.

Comment: @bottleneck , I already profile . It stop when reach stored procedure command and then program show timeout message .It's strange .This message does not show every save time .May be for the first time or sometime. I used this program with other database. It does not get error. Only one shop gets this error.

Comment: then you need to check why your stored procedure is taking time. If that can't be optimized then increasing the timeout is the only option,

Answer (score 0):

Is somebody else keeping a transaction open that is holding up your query? Run sp_who or sp_who2 on the server to see what else is running.